# Sigma models as topological quantum field theories

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, definition, topological-field-theory, sigma-models

I'm wondering how sigma models are supposed to define TQFTs. Suppose I want to consider a 2D TQFT with target $X$  (see page 15 of https://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/ulect-72-intro.pdf)*. According to this book, my understanding is that to a closed 1-dimensional complex manifold $\Sigma$ we should assign the vector space of complex-valued functions on $C(\Sigma,M)$ (the space of maps $\Sigma\to M$). However, this space is infinite dimensional, whereas according to the axioms of TQFT the vector spaces should be finite dimensional.

Am I misunderstanding, or do sigma models just define TQFTs except that the vector spaces are infinite dimensional?

*Quantum Field Theory: Batalin–Vilkovisky Formalism and Its Applications

Comment: $\sigma$-models are *not* TQFT's. They sre ordinary field theories and depend strongly  on the geometry of the target space

Comment: @mikestone My understanding is that Chern-Simons is a sigma model: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Simons+theory

Comment: CS is not usually regarded as a TQFT, but can be associated with one as part of a Wess-Zumono term. Where did you find this claim?.

Comment: I looked at the nlab page. This is niche terminology by a small number  of category enthusiasts.  Interesting though it may be, It is not mainsteam FT terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to write somewhat of an answer. *Some* $\sigma$-models define TQFTs, but, in general, they are not topological. Dijkgraaf-Witten theory is a sigma model that is a TQFT, and it is just a finite gauge group version of Chern-Simons theory.

Fix a finite group $G$ and a spacetime $M$. Then we have a sigma model of maps $\text{Map}(M,BG)$, where $BG$ is the classifying space of the group $G$. If this is unfamiliar, all this is saying is that the fields in our theory are connections on principal $G$-bundles. In physics language, our partition function "counts $G$-bundles." You'd like to do 2d, so 2d DW theory assigns to any closed 2-manifold the number of $G$-bundles: It counts the number of maps (up to homotopy) $\text{Map}(M,BG)$, which is equivalently the number of $G$-bundles on $M$ up to isomorphism. Axioms of TQFT say that to 1-manifolds it should assign vector spaces. Which vector space? Take $S^1$ for example. The vector space we assign is just the vector space generated by the bundles on $S^1$. Explicitly, $G$-bundles on $S^1$ are equivalently maps $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb Z\to G$, so they are in 1-1 correspondence with elements of $G$. Isomorphism classes are in 1-1 correspondence with conjugacy classes of maps. Indeed, trivializing a $G$-bundle at a point on $S^1$, and then traversing around $S^1$ will give the same $G$-bundle up to conjugacy. Thus, $$Z(S^1)=\sum_{[g]\in\text{conj}(G)}\mathbb C[g],$$
where I have written $Z$ for the "partition function."

Anyways,the point is that DW theory does define a TQFT, as does Chern-Simons, but this is not true in general for sigma models. Other examples are the Rozansky-Witten twist of 3d N=4 SYM and the geometric Langlands twist of 4d N=4 SYM. Note that these are sigma models that define TQFTs, but they originate from sigma models that are *not* topological! We need to perform some kind of modification, a twisting, to obtain a topological field theory. What we assign to 1-manifolds in a 2d theory entirely depends on the theory in question; if we want it to be a TQFT as you say, then we better assign finite-dimensional vector spaces.